# Automatically put PGFPlots xtick scale label in x axis label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys

I'm trying to put `xtick scale label` (defined by pgfkey `/pgfplots/xtick scale label code/.code`) in x axis label, between variable name and unit.

I've tried executing using the option `xlabel = {$ x $ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xtick scale label code/.code} m)}` to put in but this doesn't work.

I've also tried the following `xtick scale label code/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/xlabel}{#1}}` to force PGFPlots to change my xlabel but it doesn't work as well.

I know I can do this by hand, but I'm interested in automatic approach. Is there a workaround or a solution to this?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled x ticks=true,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        %xtick scale label code/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/xlabel}{#1}},
        xlabel = {$ x $ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xtick scale label code/.code} m)},
        ylabel = {$ y $},
    ]

    \addplot[line width=3pt] coordinates {(0.0,0.0)(100,1)(400,2)(10000,0)};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output from this code is:
[image: X-axis scale label should be in x axis label.]

Comment: I was able to circumvent this with `xtick scale label code/.code={$x$ $ ( 10^{#1}$ m)},` and removing `xlabel` key but this is more of a hack than a real solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the best solution is to remove `xlabel` and use `xscale label` instead. My solution is posted below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        scaled x ticks=true,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        xtick scale label code/.code={$x$ $ ( 10^{#1}$ m)},
        xlabel = {},
        ylabel = {$ y $},
    ]

    \addplot[line width=3pt] coordinates {(0.0,0.0)(100,1)(400,2)(10000,0)};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I present a solution which came up mostly from Christian Feuersänger (the author of PGFPlots), but he allowed me to post it here.

(For the record: I added a [Feature Request](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/59/) to the PGFPlots Tracker to implement a simpler interface for that.)

For more details on how the solution works, please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the "advanced" placing of
        % the axis labels
        compat=1.3,
        % create a new style to move the `tick scale label' to the axis labels
        tick scale labels in axis labels/.code={
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/xtick scale label code/.@cmd}\temp
            % remember the original value of 'xtick scale label code':
            \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/xtick scale label code orig/.@cmd}\temp
            %
            \pgfkeysalso{
                % simply remember the value in some global macro:
                xtick scale label code/.code={
                    \gdef\xTickScale{##1}
                },
                % now, _modify_ any user-specified value of 'xlabel' by
                % appending the tick scale label.
                % In order to evaluate this modification AFTER the user
                % wrote "xlabel={$x$}", we add it to 'every axis':
                every axis/.append style={
                    % because we don't need the "binop" in this context just
                    % set it to nothing
                    tick scale binop={},
                    xlabel/.add = {}{
                        (\pgfplotsset{xtick scale label code orig=\xTickScale}\,m)
                    },
                },
            }
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % activate/load the created style
            tick scale labels in axis labels,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {
                (0.0,0.0)(100,1)(400,2)(10000,0)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Your solution is more than welcome but to me it seems a bit ambiguous: following the convention for other PGFPlots commands, I'd expect the option `tick scale labels in axis labels` to affect both axes (the one you presented affects only x-axis) and have separate `xtick scale labels in axis labels` and `ytick scale labels in axis labels` to affect x- or y-axis only.

Your Feature Request for adding this option to PGFPlots package is more than welcome and I hope that the author would consider adding this to this magnificent package.

Comment: It is true that the name could be a bit misleading, but I think it is much better than simply writing "bla". Hopefully from the following code it was clear that it is working for the x axis only. I also hope that Christian considers this to be worth to be implemented in one of the future versions.