# pgfplots, get the axis exponent in scientific notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Many times, it happens to me to produce stacked time history plots, with `xticks` and `xlabel` in common in order to save vertical space in papers.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=1.14, 
  width=200pt,
  height=100pt,
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      name = plot1,
      xticklabels={,,},
      ylabel = {$x_1$},
      xmajorgrids,
    ]
      \addplot coordinates {(1,0.0001)(2,0.0002)(3,0.0003)};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
      at=(plot1.south west), anchor=north west,
      xlabel = {$t$[s]},
      ylabel = {$x_2$},
      xmajorgrids,
    ]
      \addplot coordinates {(1,0.0002)(2,0.0004)(3,0.0006)};
    \end{axis}

  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

As one can notice, the y-axis multiplier position is a problem.
A possible solution would be specify the multiplier in every y tick label with `scaled y ticks=false`, but then the result is really heavy and space consuming.

I would like to be able to pragmatically produce the following result:

[image]

which, in my opinion, is really compact and elegant.

To do this programmatically, the exponent of the scientific notation is needed, in order to put it in the `ylabel`, something like:

```
ylabel = {$x_1 \cdot 10^{-\sci_exponent}$},
```

and then a way to get the scaled ytick label.

Is it possible?

Please, note that, differently from [Automatically put PGFPlots xtick scale label in x axis label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337635/automatically-put-pgfplots-xtick-scale-label-in-x-axis-label), I do not want just move the exponent, but I would like to invert the exponent in order to (for example) get `$10^{4}` in place of `10^{-4}`, as in the figures above.

Comment: I seem to remember that this question, or one very similar, has been asked before sometime. I couldn't find it at the moment, and I'm not even sure if it was answered, but some more searching might be fruitful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working on the solution proposed in [Automatically put PGFPlots xtick scale label in x axis label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337635/automatically-put-pgfplots-xtick-scale-label-in-x-axis-label), I came up with this totally automatic solution (even if a bit dirty):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xtick scale label code/.code={\pgfmathparse{int(-#1)}$x \cdot 10^{\pgfmathresult}$},
        every x tick scale label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)}, anchor = north},
        ytick scale label code/.code={\pgfmathparse{int(-#1)}$y \cdot 10^{\pgfmathresult}$},
        every y tick scale label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:0.5)}, anchor = south, rotate = 90},
    ]

    \addplot coordinates { (0.0001,0.001)(0.0002,0.002)(0.0003,0.003) };

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produce the following output:

[image]

and automatically adapts to the data order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

As [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351168/pgfplots-get-the-axis-exponent-in-scientific-notation#comment862688_351168) already stated in the comment below the question there was a similar question a while ago: [Automatically put PGFPlots xtick scale label in x axis label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337635/automatically-put-pgfplots-xtick-scale-label-in-x-axis-label). But I don't like the solution presented there by [Budo Zindovic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344726/95441), because this has several side effects which I don't want to mention here.

Therefore I present another solution. For more details on how it works, please have a look the comments in the code.

(Just as additional information:
I already asked Christian Feuersänger (the author of PGFPlots), if there is a possibility to only access the "scale value", but didn't get an answer so far. This would allow a much more automated solution than this one. If anybody already has an idea, I'd be very happy to know that.)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % I think it is easier to use the `groupplots' library for your purpose
    % and in case you would have the "multipliers" in the *unit part* then
    % this would be very easy with the `units' library
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.groupplots,
        pgfplots.units,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to use the improved positioning of axis labels
        compat=1.3,
        width=200pt,
        height=100pt,
        % state that we want to use the features of the `units' library
        use units=true,
        % what style do we want to use to show the units?
        unit markings=slash space,  % other options: parenthesis, square brackets
    }
% use the `siunitx' package to state (numbers and) units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            % to be consistent with the factoring, define the scaling factor here
            \def\Factor{4}
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                % we have 1 column with 2 rows of plots
                group size=1 by 2,
                % make the vertical sep a bit smaller than the default
                vertical sep=2ex,
                % we want to show the ticks and labels only at the plot at the bottom
                x descriptions at=edge bottom,
            },
            % set the xlabel and the corresponding unit; the later with the help of the
            % `siunitx' package
            xlabel= {$t$},
            x unit={\si{\second}},
            xmajorgrids,
            %%% change the scaling of the data
            % this is done automatically,
            % but to be consistent we provide it "manually" using the above defined variable
            scaled y ticks=base 10:\Factor,
            % but we don't want to show the label (here)
            ytick scale label code/.code={},
%            % both previous can be given manually with the following key
%            % (the both arguments correspond to the previous ones in reverse order)
%            scaled y ticks=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1*1e\Factor}},
            %
            % to not have to add the "multiplier" to each `ylabel' apply it as
            % prefix to all
            execute at end axis={
                % (the `pgfplotsset' is necessary, because `execute at end axis'
                % only executes *executable* code and `ylabel/.add' is no executable code.)
                \pgfplotsset{
                    ylabel/.add={\num{e\Factor}\,}{},
                }
            },
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[
            % (as it seems this has to be done at every `\nextgroupplot' manually:)
            % add the "multiplier" to each `ylabel'
            % of course also here we use the defined factor to be consistent between the
            % "automatic" scaling and the factor in the label
            ylabel={$x_1$},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates { (1,0.0001)(2,0.0002)(3,0.0003) };
        \nextgroupplot[
            ylabel={$x_2$},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates { (1,0.0002)(2,0.0004)(3,0.0006) };
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It contains a lot of interesting tricks, even if not really on topic. The main drawback is that, as I undertand from your answer, so far there is no possibility to access the "scale value".
I'm sorry, but in your solution (like in the code I used to produce the bottom plot in my question) the "scale value" in the ylabel is hard coded, which is what I would like to avoid, since it may lead to mistakes in case of data loaded from a file.

Comment: That is true, a lot of the solution is not topic related, but shows a "better" solution in general (as I think). And you are right, my solution is not fully automatic, but I edited so at least the result is always *consistent* regarding the factoring and the label by introducing a defined variable `\Factor` which used.