# remove multiplier pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to remove the multiplier (10^-3) from the plot. I want to specify it manually in the y-label:

```
\begin{frame}{Plot responses}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = {\(i(t)\)},
            ymax = 0.2,
            ymin =-0.05,
            scaled y ticks=base 10:3,
        ]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:6, 
            samples=100, 
            color=red,
        ]
        {1/6*exp(-x)-1/6*exp(-4*x)};
        \addlegendentry{\(\frac{1}{6}e^{-t}-\frac{1}{6}e^{-4t}\)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image: output of the code above]

I want to manually specify that i(t) needs to be read in milliamps (mA).
I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove or change the multiplier (10^-3) with:

```
ytick scale label code/.code={}
```

from the plot. The default value is `$\cdot 10^{#1}$` (see [pgfplots manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), section *4.15.3 Tick Scaling – Common Factors In Ticks*).

**Updated Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(i(t)\)},
        ymax = 0.2,
        ymin =-0.05,
        scaled y ticks=base 10:3,
        ytick scale label code/.code={}% <-- added to delete $\cdot 10^{#1}$
    ]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:6,
            samples=100,
            color=red,
        ]
        {1/6*exp(-x)-1/6*exp(-4*x)};

        \addlegendentry{\(\frac{1}{6}e^{-t}-\frac{1}{6}e^{-4t}\)}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: PGFPLOTS output without scale label.]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this is to just "scale" all relevant numbers. Have a look at the lines marked with `% <--`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        xlabel=$t$,
        ylabel={$i(t)$},
        ymax=200,       % <-- scaled
        ymin=-50,       % <-- scaled
    ]
        \addplot [
            domain=0:6,
            samples=101,
            color=red,
        ] {1000/6*exp(-x) - 1000/6*exp(-4*x)};  % <-- scaled
        \addlegendentry{$\frac{1}{6}e^{-t}-\frac{1}{6}e^{-4t}$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Another alternative would be to do something like shown in the answers to [pgfplots, get the axis exponent in scientific notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351168/95441).