# Pgfplots - make axis multiplier part of axis label

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{script}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$
        ]
            \addplot table {
                30000 30000
                40000 40000
                50000 50000
                60000 60000
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`pgfplots` will plot the given points just fine. The only problem for me is that it writes the axis multiplier (`10^4` in this case) at the end of the axis.

[image]

I would like to have the multiplier to be part of the respective axis label. In particular I'd like to achieve something like this:
`x [10^4]` (same for the y-label)

Therefore I thought whether there might be a way to suppress `pgfplots` from writing the multiplier itself and use some macro holding this multiplier in order to append it to my labels.

Does somebody know how to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: A couple of solutions are listed here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/337635/150114

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I need. If a Moderator sees this, he or she can mark this as a duplicate as the linked question.