# pgfplots: Changing font of binary operator

Tags: pgfplots, fonts

What is the command to modify the font of the **binary operators** of a pgfplot?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[scaled ticks=true] 
\addplot coordinates {(200000,0.00005) (400000,0.00010) (600000,0.00020)}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Example** (binary operator are marked in yellow)

[image]

Comment: And what should the centered dot be changed into?

Comment: Good question. I would prefer the 'times' symbol of my sans-serif in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @caverac that the `ytick scale label code/.code=` key is the thing you want to change, and think it would have been appropriate to mention [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344726/121799) in this context. What I do, however, not like is that (s)he nests tikzpictures.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
    scaled ticks=true,
    xtick scale label code/.code={$\mathsf{\cdot 10^{#1}}$},
    ytick scale label code/.code={$\mathsf{\cdot 10^{#1}}$},
    ] 
    \addplot coordinates {(200000,0.00005) (400000,0.00010) (600000,0.00020)}; 
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll be happy to remove my answer if caverac removes the nested tikzpictures, refers to the earlier answer (and answers the question).

Comment: You're right, I changed the highlighted text

Comment: That's the thing, I was searching! Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `xtick scale label code` option

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
    scaled ticks=true,
    ytick scale label code/.code={$\mathrm{\cdot 10^{#1}}$},
    xtick scale label code/.code={$\mathit{\cdot 10^{#1}}$},
    ] 
    \addplot coordinates {(200000,0.00005) (400000,0.00010) (600000,0.00020)}; 
  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
I highlighted the label just to emphasize that it can be changed through `xtick scale label code`, changed it to a couple of different fonts now. Thanks to @marmot and @remco for their feedback

Comment: OP was asking about changing the font of the labels, not about adding the highlighting...

Comment: @remco Thanks! I understand that, my point is that the style of the label can be changed with `xtick scale label code`

Comment: I can no longer delete my answer. So I upvoted some of your other excellent answers (those which I did not upvote before), hoping that's OK with you.

Comment: It’s alright, no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

PgfPlot writes the automatic scaling labels in the current math fonts (through "\ensuremath"). So to use a different font for your axis labels, you can either force PgfPlots to use a text font, or change the math fonts you use.

With LuaLatex, using the package `unicode-math` and `\setmathfont{xxx}`, you can set the math fonts to 'xxx'.